# Solving quartic equation? (Cardano/Ferrari)

Tags: polynomials, roots

today I've written a little Code-Snippet that is based upon the steps that are mentionned in [this wikipedia-Article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartische_Gleichung) to solve a general quartic polynom.

Here's my matlab-implementation:

```
function ply4_roots = roots_cardano (dbl_p4, dbl_p3, dbl_p2, ...
    dbl_p1, dbl_p0)

    % solving a quartic equation with method of Ferrari

    dbl_alpha = -(3/8)*(dbl_p3^2)/(dbl_p4^2)+(dbl_p2/dbl_p4);
    dbl_beta = (1/8)*(dbl_p3^3)/(dbl_p4^3)-(1/2) ...
        *(dbl_p3*dbl_p2)/(dbl_p4^2)+ (dbl_p1/dbl_p4);
    dbl_gamma = -(3/256)*(dbl_p3^4)/(dbl_p4^4)+(1/16) ...
        *(dbl_p3^2*dbl_p2)/(dbl_p4^3) - (1/4) ...
        *(dbl_p3*dbl_p1)/(dbl_p4^2)+(dbl_p0/dbl_p4);

    dbl_pp = -(1/12)*dbl_alpha^2-dbl_gamma;
    dbl_qq = -(1/108)*dbl_alpha^3+(1/3)*dbl_alpha* ...
        dbl_gamma-(1/8)*dbl_beta^2;

    if dbl_pp~=0

        dbl_uu = (-(1/2)*dbl_qq+((1/4)*dbl_qq^2+(1/27)* ...
            dbl_pp^3)^(1/2))^(1/3);
        dbl_yy = -(5/6)*dbl_alpha+dbl_uu-(1/3)*(dbl_pp/dbl_uu);

    else

        dbl_yy = -(5/6)*dbl_alpha-(dbl_qq)^(1/3);

    end

    dbl_ww = (dbl_alpha+2*dbl_yy)^(1/2);

    ply4_roots(1) = -(1/4)*(dbl_p3/dbl_p4)+(1/2)*(1*dbl_ww+ ...
        1*(-(dbl_alpha+2*dbl_yy)-2*(dbl_alpha+ ...
        1*(dbl_beta/dbl_ww)))^(1/2));

    ply4_roots(2) = -(1/4)*(dbl_p3/dbl_p4)+(1/2)*(1*dbl_ww+ ...
        (-1)*(-(dbl_alpha+2*dbl_yy)-2*(dbl_alpha+ ...
        1*(dbl_beta/dbl_ww)))^(1/2));

    ply4_roots(3) = -(1/4)*(dbl_p3/dbl_p4)+(1/2)*((-1)*dbl_ww+ ...
        (-1)*(-(dbl_alpha+2*dbl_yy)-2*(dbl_alpha+ ...
        (-1)*(dbl_beta/dbl_ww)))^(1/2));

    ply4_roots(4) = -(1/4)*(dbl_p3/dbl_p4)+(1/2)*((-1)*dbl_ww+ ...
        1*(-(dbl_alpha+2*dbl_yy)-2*(dbl_alpha+ ...
        (-1)*(dbl_beta/dbl_ww)))^(1/2));

    % sort results with bubble-sort
    for ii=4:-1:1

        for idx=1:3

            if ply4_roots(idx)>ply4_roots(idx+1)

                value=ply4_roots(idx);
                ply4_roots(idx) = ply4_roots(idx+1);
                ply4_roots(idx+1) = value;

            end

        end

    end

end
```

In principle, it seems that the script works for examples like:

```
>> roots_cardano(1,-4,-1,16,-12)

ans =

  -2     1     2     3
```

But, if I try it for

```
>> roots_cardano(2, -4, -3, 7, -2)

ans =

  -1.3660 + 0.0000i   0.3660 - 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   2.0000 - 0.0000i
```

I get "some" complex results which shouldn't be there. Matlab's root-finder gives:

```
>> roots([2 -4 -3 7 -2])

ans =

   -1.3660
    2.0000
    1.0000
    0.3660
```

what underlines that there are no complex parts in the solution.

For another example, it is somehow 'reversed':

```
>> roots_cardano(1,-14,44,-40,0)

ans =

         0    2.0000    2.0000   10.0000
```

... and matlab gives:

```
>> roots([1 -14 44 -40 0])

ans =

        0          
  10.0000          
   2.0000 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 - 0.0000i
```

and one last example:

```
    coef_cply4 = 2.03975258797202e-14
    coef_cply3 = 5.29694855354049e-14
    coef_cply2 = 2.83428012361253e-14
    coef_cply1 = 3.02190058771691e-15
    coef_cply0 = 2.80521515614180e-20

    >> roots_cardano(coef_cply4, coef_cply3, coef_cply2, coef_cply1, coef_cply0)

    ans =

      -1.9100 + 0.0000i  -0.5444 - 0.0000i  -0.1425 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i

>> roots([coef_cply4 coef_cply3 coef_cply2 coef_cply1 coef_cply0])

ans =

   -1.9100
   -0.5444
   -0.1425
   -0.0000
```

... so I guess that there could be somewhere a mistake in my script. Unfortunately I did not find it until now.

It would be great if someone could help me ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Doesn't Ferrari's solution work only in specific cases? I think the matlab 'roots' function uses numerical methods.

Comment: Mmh, I don't know. - All polynomials that I have to solve are real ones (I know that they've no complex solution) ... and I was looking for a quicker method to find the roots. (Before, I used the bairstow-method ... )

Or is there another way to find the roots 'quicker'; I mean without loops etc ... ?

Comment: Are the complex parts negligible? You're only displaying to the default four decimal places (and they're all zero), not the full floating point values. Numerical approaches will have small errors. You also shouldn't expect the order of the roots or numerical errors to be the same as those from Matlab's method, which uses a completely different algorithm.

Comment: @horchler ... yes, they're negligible. (I have to find the roots of the last example I added - the one with those '*e-14'-factors.) - I also have to transfer my script in a different language that doesn't know complex numbers, so if there occur something like sqrt(-a) where a is a number, the program will crash ... and therefore I am looking for a kind of 'workaround' ...

Comment: The Wikipedia article solves numerical cases. Compare to what your code does.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. Which article? ... I know that my code gives an analytical solution. I've also written a numerical solver that uses the Bairstow-method - this works pretty well. Unfortunately it is costly 'cause I have to do a lot of calculations in another program routine. So I looked for a quicker algorithm and thought that this is the analytical method if I can get rid of those problems I mentionned before ...

Comment: Hem, the article that you pointed.

Comment: @Yves Daoust ... mh, but this article is about how to solve quartic equations analytically. Maybe I misunderstood something but ... I don't know

Comment: The problem might be that your algoithm is analytical, but the representation of real numbers is numerical (that is a floating point representation). This might lead to "infinitesimal" remains of the imaginary part.

Comment: It solves numerical cases.

Comment: @DanielR ... I understand. But is it somehow possible to "drop" those imaginary parts?

Comment: ... I mean like if they're smaller than a definied "tolerance" ...

Comment: Well, I guess you could discard them if they are below a certain threshold, but I wouldn't call that a very reliable solution. Without analyzing your algorithm in detail I'd say that the only way to go is to resort to some kind of symbolic manipulation software, such as the symbolic toolbox in Matlab. This way, the intermediate values are kept with infinite precision, since they are treated as algebraic entities.

Comment: What language are you transferring this to? Almost all languages have very good libraries for handling complex data types. Don't create unnecessary problems for yourself.

Comment: @horchler it is the back-end of a commercial finite-elemente software, called 'sofistik' and the language is something fortran-based.
but I just found out that my bairstow solver is quicker that I thought - unfortunately I forgot that I included a kind of "tolerance" for finding the roots and that i had set it to '1e-12' ... now I changed it to '1e-4' and it works well, and a little bit quicker =)